# Differential and integral calculus. Improper integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have to analyze the character of the following improper integral:

$$\int_{1}^{3}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(-x^3+x^2+9x-9)^{1/2}}}$$
I don't really know how to analyze it.

I have decomposed the denominator as: $[(x+3)(x-3)(x-1)]^{1/4}$.
I  am not sure how I would find the answer to this question. I am trying to use the limit comparison test or the limit criterion, but I don't see how I would get the answer.

Comment: If you are only asked to analyze it and not calculate it, you can say that the function is ubounded at both ends of the interval of integration. You can then set up the limits you will be using when you would have to calculate to find the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $1<x\le2$, $5\le(3-x)(3+x)<8$ and
$$\int_1^2\frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/4}}=\left.\frac43(x-1)^{3/4}\right|_1^2=\frac43$$
So
$$\begin{align}\frac438^{-1/4}&=8^{-1/4}\int_1^2\frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/4}}\le\int_1^2\frac{dx}{\left((3-x)(x+3)(x-1)\right)^{1/4}}\\
&\le5^{-1/4}\int_1^2\frac{dx}{(x-1)^{1/4}}=\frac435^{-1/4}\end{align}$$
Similarly you can show that
$$\frac4312^{-1/4}\le\int_2^3\frac{dx}{\left((3-x)(x+3)(x-1)\right)^{1/4}}\le\frac435^{-1/4}$$
So we may conclude that
$$\frac43\left(8^{-1/4}+12^{-1/4}\right)\le\int_1^3\frac{dx}{\left((3-x)(x+3)(x-1)\right)^{1/4}}\le\frac83\left(5^{-1/4}\right)$$
It converges because is is bounded by convergent integrals.